# jQuery isnt processing properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two jQuery scripts in header (watch out for the order)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="basic_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="additional_script.js"></script>
```

Both scripts are having the basic structure as:

```
jQuery(function(){
   //scriptsMainContent
});
```

I defined function `switchFunction()`  in `basic_script.js`'s *scriptsMainContent*  but when I use it in the `additional_script.js`'s *scriptsMainContent* I get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: switchFunction is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `jQuery(function(){});`

Comment: Show us where `switchFunction()` is defined in the actual code. Sounds like it's simply not in the same scope

Comment: Do you have jQuery defined before those script tags?

Comment: @helion3 I just showed you - what else do you want to see? O.o http://jsfiddle.net/6esMw/ does this helps you? (same error behaviour) #Satpal Just No. Are you familiar with jQuery's document.ready()?

Comment: You're defining the function inside the jquery closure function. Check Ethan's answer. I was asking you to show us where it was defined, the fiddle did that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `jQuery(function(){})`, you're essentially *inside an anonymous function*.  So anything you declare with `var` will be function-scope, and therefore not available outside of that function.  What you've probably got it something like this:

**Script 1**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var i_think_this_is_global_but_it_is_not = 'foo';
});
```

**Script 2**

```
jQuery(function(){
    console.log(i_think_this_is_global_but_it_is_not);  // logs 'undefined'
});
```

What you WANT is this:

**Script 1**

```
var i_am_global = 'foo';

jQuery(function(){
    i_am_global = 'bar';
});
```

**Script 2**

```
jQuery(function(){
    console.log(i_am_global);  // logs 'bar'
});
```

As an aside, it's generally a poor idea to "pollute" global space inside scripts.  Here's a better way to handle this:

```
<script>
    // define globals
    var global = 'I'm a global!';
</script>
<!-- var 'global' will be available to the following scripts -->
<script src="/js/script1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script2.js"></script>
```

An even BETTER way to handle this still is to remove the dependency on global variables.  For example, have `script1.js` and `script2.js` expose functions (I'll call them `stuff1` and `stuff2`) that take a shared object:

```
<script src="/js/script1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script2.js"></script>
<script>
    var context = {
        foo = 'bar'
    }
    stuff1(context);  // exposed in script1.js
    stuff2(context);  // exposed in script2.js
</script>
```

**UPDATE: Functions**

The OP, in the comments, revealed that the problem was with a function.  The thing with functions is that they are *always* declared in function scope.  There's always an implicit `var` even if you don't explicitly write it.  In other words:

```
function foo() {
   // bar defined in foo scope
   function bar() {
   }
}
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
    // bar (which happens to be a function)
    // defined in foo scope
    var bar = function() {
    }
}
```

The only way to explicitly define a function in global scope without actually being in a global scope is to know the name of the global object (which is `window` if you're in a browser):

```
function foo() {
    // bar defined in global (window) scope
    window.bar = function() {
    }
}
```

Note that the above approach (using `window` explicitly) is only necessary if you're declaring a function from within another function.  This also declares a function in the global scope:

```
// declared in global scope
function foo() {
}

jQuery(function(){
    // declared in local scope
    function bar() {
    }
    // okay to use foo OR bar here
    foo();  // from global scope
    bar();  // from local scope
});
```

Then when you use that script:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
    foo();   // works, foo in global scope
    bar();   // fail, bar not in global scope
</script>
```

**Functions and jQuery**

The OP also went on to ask if it would be a problem to use jQuery selectors inside a function that is itself outside of `jQuery(function(){})`.  The answer is yes, that's fine, because the function is only being declared, not invoked.  You can even declare such functions before jQuery is even available, as long as you don't invoke it before jQuery is ready.  For example:

```
<script>
    function foo() {
        // okay to use jQuery even though it hasn't been
        // defined yet; we're only declaring function
        $('#thing').text('hello from jQuery!');
    }
    foo();  // invocation: THIS will fail
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    foo();  // this will fail unless this script is located
            // AFTER the <body>
    jQuery(function(){
        foo();  // this is safe; jQuery is loaded AND
                // the DOM is ready
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is with a function - the function is defined regulary with no var - I thought that all jQuery's ready()s are merging to the one scope arent they?

Comment: That's incorrect.  And functions have an implicit `var` in front of them.  In other words, writing `function foo() {}` is the same thing as writing `var foo = function() {}`.

Comment: No, you're passing them individual anonymous functions which are executed when the document ready event is called

Comment: @helion3 ah thats the thing

Comment: @EthanBrown you read my mind and added the function-brief&clear-explanation :) So the `window.prop` is the way to go for me since I work with web browser :) , Many Thanks.

Comment: jave.web, if I need to export a function from a script, I just write it in the implicit global scope.  so, if i wanted to export the function `foo` and THEN do stuff when the DOM is ready, I would do this:  `function foo() {}; jQuery(function(){/* do stuff...call foo if you want */})`.  `foo` will then be declared in the global scope and you don't have to know the name of the global scope object.

Comment: And what if the foo() contains jQuery selectors - wouldnt that be a problem?

Comment: No it wouldn't, because you're only _declaring_ a function; it won't be a problem unless the function is _invoked_ before jQuery (or the DOM) is available.

Comment: So I tried to put this function of mine -as was-(no window use) outside (explicitly before) the jQuery's ready call and even though it contains the jQuery selectors, **it is working** because I am using it in the jQuery's readys only - just as you said @EthanBrown

Answer (score 1):

switchFunction is just in scope of local function in basic_script.js.
You need to move it out the jQuery(function() {}); to use in global.

UPD:

**base_scipt.js**

```
function someFn(context) {
    alert('I have been runned from ' + context);
}

JQuery(function() {
    someFn('base_script.js');
});
```

**additional_scipt.js**

```
JQuery(function() {
    someFn('additional_scipt.js');
});
```

You may see 2 alerts, all of them will be called from "JQuery's ready".

Comment: I need the function only to be called inside jQuery's ready , would be storing the function into some window.prop a solution?

Comment: You can call it from wherever you want, but you need to define it in global, if you want to use it in defferen scripts, which content is placed into anonybous functions.

Comment: Are you having a Bflue? ... Anyway what if the function contains jQuery selectors?

Comment: You misstyped the anonymous as anonybous so I just asumed you have a flue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var t = jQuery.noConflict();
    and then your code //
t(function(){
   //code
});
```

Comment: Surely interesting approach, could you show a working fiddle example ? :)